# Duplicating POCO code in different layers with code-first migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I'm interested in using entity framework - code first migrations with a new database, and I have some questions/concerns about duplicating POCO code in the data and business layers.

The idea is to have a data access layer containing my POCO entities all decorated with database schema type items like string lengths, foreign key related things that don't work out of the box, and whatever else.    This layer will also act as a repository that will return scalar values, entities, aggregates, and IEnumerables.

Above that will be the business layer, which will handle talking to the repository, and a bunch of business logic.

At the top is the presentation layer.  This layer talks to the business layer, and has no idea about the data layer – all it understands is view models.  I would implement the MVC pattern at this layer, using only view models.

The issue I am running into is related to where I should do the mapping between my view models and my data models.  If I define the view models in my presentation layer, the business layer will not know they exist.

- Am I better off defining the view models in the business layer, or do I need a set of domain models in the business layer that the presentation layer would be aware of and be able to perform mapping against?

  - Would an additional set of domain models just be an egregious duplication of the models defined in the data layer?

Comment: The models would have to live somewhere that both the client AND the business layer can reference.  That way, they act as a data contract between the two layers.  You could let the business layer interact with the DAL however you see fit, and always return the agreed upon data contract back to the client.  This would mean that your models are in a separate project than your views and controllers.

Comment: I had thought of that - It would seem weird having an empty model folder in my MVC project, but maybe that's just something I'd need to get over.  I'm hoping to learn about other options that I have no idea exist :)

Comment: Are you sure the business logic should reference view models?

Comment: Im not too sure to be honest.  Hoping to get a feel for other people's experience with this.  The idea of handing a view model off to the presentation layer sounds nice, but I'm wondering if there are pitfalls that I might run in to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the scope of the project, I usually use one of the two methods below:

1) have a set of domain models separately from all layers, and then have all layers reference them. 
Pros: layers are still independent, no model duplication, no need to map layer models.
Cons: change in domain model would affect all layers, e.g. DB change may break display

2) have models in each layer. Business layer would map its own models to those of data layer, presentation layer would map its models to those of business layer
Pros: every layer does one thing, changes in underlying models to not propagate through layer
Cons: duplication of the models is likely and mapping needs to be maintained

First approach works best for smaller apps and "direct updates" scenarios, second works better in large projects with multiple moving components.

P.S. "defining the view models in the business layer" is a definite no-no.

Comment: Thanks for breaking down the different options.  I think it's going to make sense to define all of my models in a common assembly.  The only thing that feels odd is that I'm using data annotations for database schema info in a layer outside of data access.

Comment: if that makes you feel weird, you can always keep your poco's clean and map your entities in a separate assembly using EntityTypeConfiguration<>